# R save() not producing any output but no error

Tags: r

I am brand new to R and I am trying to run some existing code that should clean up an input .csv then save the cleaned data to a different location as a .RData file. This code has run fine for the previous owner.

The code seems to be pulling the .csv and cleaning it just fine. It also looks like the save is running (there are no errors) but there is no output in the specified location. I thought maybe R was having a difficult time finding the location, but it's pulling the input data okay and the destination is just a sub folder.

After a full day of extensive Googling, I can't find anything related to a save just not working.

Example code below:

```
save(data, file = "C:\\Users\\my_name\\Documents\\Project\\Data.RData", sep="")
```

Comment: Remove `sep = ""` and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to believe you don't see any errors - unless something has switched errors off:

```
> data = 1:10
> save(data, file="output.RData", sep="")
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : invalid first argument
```

Its a misleading error, the problem is the third argument, which doesn't do anything. Remove and it works:

```
> save(data, file="output.RData")
>
```

`sep` is used as an argument in writing CSV files to separate columns. `save` writes binary data which doesn't have rows and columns.